# Replace Returned Value in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have been trying to replace the values in column of returned data from a SQL query.

After quite a bit of Googling I have tried to use REPLACE and CASE but with no luck so I am after a bit of help with it.

The column I want to manipulate is ParentMsgClassID. So in a bit of simple pseudo code I want the following to happen.

```
IF ParentMsgClassID = 1000 VALUE = Audit
IF ParentMsgClassID = 2000 VALUE = Security
IF ParentMsgClassID = 3000 VALUE = Operations
```

My Select statement is as follows.

```
select
/*MsgSourceType Columns*/
ST.MsgSourceTypeID,
ST.[Name] AS MsgSourceTypeName,

/*MPERuleToMsgSourceType Columns*/
MRMST.MPERuleRegexID,

/*MPERule Columns*/
MPER.MPERuleID,
MPER.CommonEventID,
MPER.FullName AS MPERuleFullName,
MPER.BaseRule,

/*Common Event Columns*/
CE.MsgClassID,
CE.[Name] AS commonEventName,

/*MsgClass Columns*/
MC.ParentMsgClassID,
MC.[Name] AS MsgClassName,
MC.FullName AS MsgClassFullName,
MC.ShortDesc AS MsgShortDesc

from MsgSourceType AS ST

inner join MPERuleToMsgSourceType AS MRMST on ST.MsgSourceTypeID = MRMST.MsgSourceTypeID
inner join MPERule AS MPER on MPER.MPERuleRegexID = MRMST.MPERuleRegexID
inner join CommonEvent AS CE on MPER.CommonEventID = CE.CommonEventID
inner join MsgClass as MC on CE.MsgClassID =  MC.MsgClassID

where ST.[Name] like 'syslog - Palo Alto Firewall';
```

Any help would be greatly received, also I'm not a DBA so the above is just cobbled together and may be sub-optimal.

As per the comment below I have tried to use CASE but it didn't work. I have included the query for reference.

```
select

/*MsgSourceType Columns*/
ST.MsgSourceTypeID,
ST.[Name] AS MsgSourceTypeName,

/*MPERuleToMsgSourceType Columns*/
MRMST.MPERuleRegexID,

/*MPERule Columns*/
MPER.MPERuleID,
MPER.CommonEventID,
MPER.FullName AS MPERuleFullName,
MPER.BaseRule,

/*Common Event Columns*/
CE.MsgClassID,
CE.[Name] AS commonEventName,

/*MsgClass Columns*/
MC.ParentMsgClassID,
MC.[Name] AS MsgClassName,
MC.FullName AS MsgClassFullName,
MC.ShortDesc AS MsgShortDesc,

CASE MC.ParentMsgClassID
    WHEN 1000 THEN 'Audit'
    WHEN 2000 THEN 'Security'
    WHEN 3000 THEN 'Operations'
END AS ParentMsgClassText

from MsgSourceType AS ST

inner join MPERuleToMsgSourceType AS MRMST on ST.MsgSourceTypeID = MRMST.MsgSourceTypeID
inner join MPERule AS MPER on MPER.MPERuleRegexID = MRMST.MPERuleRegexID
inner join CommonEvent AS CE on MPER.CommonEventID = CE.CommonEventID
inner join MsgClass as MC on CE.MsgClassID =  MC.MsgClassID

where ST.[Name] like 'syslog - Palo Alto Firewall';
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your question mentions one column.  Your code references a bunch.  Simplify!

Comment: Specify an "else" in the CASE clause and see what happens.

Comment: @FarhadRahmanifard, thanks for your suggestions. I just tried that and no luck. As I said below the column isn't even picking up the alias column heading of ParentMsgClassText. It's like the CASE statement is being ignored.

Comment: Even when remove all other columns in select?

Comment: @FarhadRahmanifard If I just run select ParentMsgClassID, CASE MsgClass.ParentMsgClassID WHEN 1000 THEN 'Audit' WHEN 2000 THEN 'Security' ELSE 'Operations' END AS ParentMsgClassText from MsgClass; it works. So it must have something to do with the wider query.

Comment: @FarhadRahmanifard, you've sorted it. If you look at where I added the CASE statement above it was after I had selected the column headings from the MsgClass table. It seems the CASE statement needed to be directly after the column I am trying to manipulate.

Comment: I am glad it works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `CASE` expression would seem to do what you want here:

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE MC.ParentMsgClassID WHEN 1000 THEN 'Audit'
                             WHEN 2000 THEN 'Security'
                             WHEN 3000 THEN 'Operations' END AS ParentMsgClassText
```

This can just be added to your current `SELECT` statement, from what I can see.

If you want these labels to become logically part of the table itself, then you are either looking for an *update* with a new column, or maybe just add a computed column.  For the latter option:

```
ALTER TABLE MsgClass
ADD ParentMsgClassText AS (
    CASE MC.ParentMsgClassID WHEN 1000 THEN 'Audit'
                             WHEN 2000 THEN 'Security'
                             WHEN 3000 THEN 'Operations' END);
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. The query will run but the alteration does not take place. I did wonder if this might be because of the data being returned is an INT and not a VarChar so I tried to use casting but that also didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "alteration?"  I'm not familiar with this term in the context of a SQL query.

Comment: Alteration as in, I am trying to alter the value 1000 into being Audit. So what I was trying to explain is that while what you suggested ran OK, it did not alter the output in any way. i.e. I got the same result as I did before your suggestion. Please see my edited post above to see how I incorporated your suggestion, I may have gotten it wrong.

Comment: I'm stumped.  Are you saying that the `CASE` expression you added does _not_ generate the text values you want?

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. What's more, the column name does not pick up the alias that is assigned as part of the CASE function. It's like it's completely ignored. Is it possible SQL Studio has cached something that is stopping the results from being displayed correctly?

Comment: You seem like you might be fairly new to using SQL.  A `SELECT` does _not_ alter the values in a table, it only retrieves them, and maybe presents them a certain way.  If you want the labels to "stick," you will either have to add a new column, or maybe add a computed column.  I suggest the latter option, and I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Hi Tim, I don't use SQL on a day-to-day basis but I have always been able to cobble together what I need. Fully understand that the SELECT query is just retrieving results from the tables within a DB. What I want to happen here is substitute a value with a string each time it occurs. i.e. I want to change the value 1000 in the ParentMsgClassID column with the word Audit each time it is retrieved by the query. This SELECT query is going to be used in a script elsewhere and it seems neater to perform the substitution here than doing it later in the script.

Comment: yes I understand it should work, what I am saying is that it is not having the desired effect. i.e. the SELECT query functions the same if I add your additions or just leave it as I had it originally. That is the reason I asked if it was possible the SQL Manager Studio had cached the results somehow. Looking at your second suggestion you are saying that I should alter the table itself, or have I misunderstood that? Assuming my understanding is correct, I cannot do that as the DB is part of the backend of an application, to alter it would put it out of support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a case as Tim showed in another answer, you can also use a join to an existing table (mapping table) or a table you make up on spot.  Consider if you had another table called map that looked like this:

```
Key  Value
1000 'Audit'
2000 'Security'
3000 'Operations'
```

Then you could modify your SQL by adding the following lines:

```
 SELECT
   -- all existing stuff
   MAP.VALUE as ParentMsgClassText
 FROM -- as exists
 JOIN MAP ON MAP.Key = ParentMsgClassID
```

You can also "make" the map on the spot like this:

```
 SELECT
   -- all existing stuff
   MAP.VALUE as ParentMsgClassText
 FROM -- as exists
 JOIN (
   VALUES
     (1000, 'Audit'),
     (2000, 'Security'),
     (3000, 'Operations')
 ) AS MAP(Key,Value) ON MAP.Key = ParentMsgClassID
```

Personally I prefer this way to using CASE -- many SQL products will run faster and if you make the external table it is clearly easier to maintain -- you can change the table to change the lookup without having to change the SQL code.

Comment: I can't add tables to this DB. I am pulling data out of an application that uses SQL as part of its backend. Adding a table or modifying it in any way would put the application out of support.

Comment: @simon -- you did not bother to read my answer carefully -- my second code sample does not require you to change any existing DB objects.

Comment: I did read your answer but the making the map on the spot version did not execute because there were syntax errors with 'Audit', 'Security', 'Operations' and Key. Perhaps if you include the while query I could copy and paste to check if it works? That would save any mistakes I might make transferring your suggestion into SQL.

Comment: @simon -- I was missing a comma -- please see new version above.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has come from a combination of responses I had to this question from @Tim Biegeleisen & @FarhadRahmanifard

Tim was completely correct in saying that using the CASE statement could achieve what I wanted to. However, my implementation of it was incorrect, see the edit in my original post above.

Where Farhad helped was by asking me to isolate what I wanted to do from the rest of the query. Once we had done that it occurred to me to put the CASE statement directly after the column I wanted to manipulate.

The working code is below for reference.

```
select

    /*MsgSourceType Columns*/
    ST.MsgSourceTypeID,
    ST.[Name] AS MsgSourceTypeName,

    /*MPERuleToMsgSourceType Columns*/
    MRMST.MPERuleRegexID,

    /*MPERule Columns*/
    MPER.MPERuleID,
    MPER.CommonEventID,
    MPER.FullName AS MPERuleFullName,
    MPER.BaseRule,

    /*Common Event Columns*/
    CE.MsgClassID,
    CE.[Name] AS commonEventName,

    /*MsgClass Columns*/
    MC.ParentMsgClassID,

    CASE MC.ParentMsgClassID
        WHEN 1000 THEN 'Audit'
        WHEN 2000 THEN 'Security'
        ELSE 'Operations'
    END AS ParentMsgClassText,

    MC.[Name] AS MsgClassName,
    MC.FullName AS MsgClassFullName,
    MC.ShortDesc AS MsgShortDesc

from MsgSourceType AS ST

inner join MPERuleToMsgSourceType AS MRMST on ST.MsgSourceTypeID = MRMST.MsgSourceTypeID
inner join MPERule AS MPER on MPER.MPERuleRegexID = MRMST.MPERuleRegexID
inner join CommonEvent AS CE on MPER.CommonEventID = CE.CommonEventID
inner join MsgClass as MC on CE.MsgClassID =  MC.MsgClassID

where ST.[Name] like 'syslog - Palo Alto Firewall';
```